# Adding Joda Time to Android Studio

Tags: android, jodatime, libraries

I got the file from [the Joda site](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases) and followed these instructions [for adding libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk)  but when I get to the Gradle sync I end up with the error:

**Gradle Sync**

```
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

**Gradle Build**

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. 
> Cannot evaluate module joda : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

A bit confused, I looked around and read that the library should have it's own gradle files but the joda package doesn't. When I try to use `import org.joda.time;` it can't resolve `joda`. Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your gradle build configuration file.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

in app/build.gradle file, add like this-

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

You don't need to do anything else.

You need the latest release, check out the release page https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases and change the version accordingly.

Comment: I am getting this exception when i run the project: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

Comment: using `compile 'joda-time:joda-time:+' ` new versions will be downloaded automatically

Comment: @JacopoGrassi: Granting unlimited trust (aka depending on most recent version (`+`) you seem to recommend) is pretty simply very unwise. You should always depend on last version you tested it works for you, not the most recent one unconditionally.

Comment: Just a friendly reminder that 2.9.2 is out now: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases

Comment: @Saket Jain, your edit does not make sense mate as it is already clearly described how to get the latest release version. We don't need to update the answer with each version release.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha: True. I'll keep in mind from next time!

Comment: I am getting exception when i add this library in gradle.  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2...

Comment: you should ask a new question regarding this.

Comment: I get `Failed to resolve: 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3' ` when I try sync my project?

Comment: compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.3', are you sure there is no typo in your gradle dependencies?

Comment: @Zapnologica uncheck offline mode in File->Settings->Gradle and it might work

Comment: Can someone explain to me why this works? It's because `joda-time` is in the Maven central repo, and thus we can include it in our gradle, correct?

Comment: I think a better place to look for updates is [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time)

Comment: @Kenneth Worden, Yes, you are right.
- [https://dl.bintray.com/jodastephen/maven](https://bintray.com/jodastephen/maven/joda-time%3Ajoda-time)
- [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.9)

Answer (score 15):

I added `joda time` via `File/Project Structure/Modules-App/Dependencies`.

[image]

Clicking on `+` and `Library dependency` brings you to the dialog:

[image]

Here you can search for joda and add the actual version to your project. If you add it this way you don't have to manually download the newest version from github or manually write something into your build.gradle file. Android Studio does it all for you.

Answer (score 5):

I completely prefer to use `jitpack.io` repository.

In this case, you should get `GitHub` links of joda-time (just a simple search) and go to [Jitpack.IO](https://jitpack.io/) then search for the github link.

After all, you should get this page and do the instructions.

https://jitpack.io/#JodaOrg/joda-time/v2.9.4

Just sync your gradle and all done...