# How can I compare hours?

Tags: java, android, time, hour, java.util.calendar

I am building an app, and I need to know how to compare two hours.

For example, my store opens at 6:30 AM and closes at 5:00 PM.

I need to show in a `TextView` that after 5 PM my store is closed, and after 6:30 AM my store is open, from Monday to Friday.

How can I do this? This is my attempt:

```java
public void timer() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int open = 6:30; // 1 ERROR HERE WITH ":"
    int close = 17;

    if (timeOfDay < close) {
        hour.setText.("OPEN");
    }
}
```

But I am getting multiple errors. One in int open when I put 06:30 with ":"; two with limit of Monday to Friday.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no date literals in Java. I suggest using an `java.time.Instant`

Comment: I suggest using the new java.time packages. You can use it on Android with this library https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP . Reasons see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688736/are-java-util-date-and-java-util-calendar-deprecated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You should be using the Java 8 Date & Time library, because Calendar and Date are obsolete.**

The `LocalTime` class should be sufficient.

```
LocalTime open = LocalTime.of(6, 30);
LocalTime closed = LocalTime.of(17, 0);

LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();
if (currentTime.isBefore(open) || currentTime.isAfter(closed)) {
    // Closed
}
```

You could then use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class to format the time into the desired format.

If you want to also take the day of the week into consideration while determining the opening times of your shop, then you could use `LocalDateTime` in conjunction with abovementioned example:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

// The opening days. Static import these from java.time.DayOfWeek
Set<DayOfWeek> daysOpen = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
    MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY));
// Opening and closing times
LocalTime timeOpen = LocalTime.of(6, 30);
LocalTime timeClosed = LocalTime.of(17, 0);

if (!daysOpen.contains(now.getDayOfWeek()) || now.toLocalTime().isBefore(timeOpen) || now.toLocalTime().isAfter(timeClosed)) {
    System.out.println("Closed");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Open");
}
```

Comment: For Android before API level 26 you need this: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: :( not work show me this `Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalTime`, and i follow steps from link and does not work either

Comment: Java 8 is supported from API level 26. If you are targeting a lower API level, then you could use Joda Time instead. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675173/adding-joda-time) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237563/adding-joda-time-to-android-studio).

Comment: Or just include ThreeTenAPB, as @leonardkraemer mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The constant `HOUR_OF_DAY` is an integer representing only the hour. I would suggest to use the method `getTime()` ([see this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar#getTime())) and then work with the returned `Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a very concise way to do this, but perhaps you can use this method

```
public boolean isOpen(Calendar c) {
   int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
   return (hour < 17 && (hour > 6 || (hour == 6 && minute >=30)));
}
```

This should return true if it is between 6:30 and 17:00 and false at any other time

(If the hour is less than 17, and
(the hour is greater than 6, or the hour is 6 and the minutes are 30 or higher))

Answer (score -1):

The `HOUR_OF_DAY field` works like this.

```
10:04:15 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.
```

You can't get `6:30 am` because it only tells you what hour it is not minute.

You can get minutes by calling `MINUTE`.

A few changes would be:

```
public void timer () {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minuteOfHour = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); -> same as Hour
    int open = 6; -> you shouldn't use ':' with an int
    int openMinutes = 30;
    int close = 17;

    if(timeOfDay >= open && minuteOfHour >= openMinutes && timeOfDay < close){
        hour.setText.("OPEN");
    }}
```

Comment: Excuse me, your answer demonstrates very well why the `Calendar` class was given up and replaced by java.time (the modern Java date and time API). If time now is 8:05 in the morning, `minuteOfHour` will be less than `openMinutes`, and your store will show as closed.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code:

```
        Calendar openingHour = Calendar.getInstance();
        openingHour.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        openingHour.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
        openingHour.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        openingHour.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar closingHour = Calendar.getInstance();
        closingHour.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        closingHour.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        closingHour.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        closingHour.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dayOfWeek = currentTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if( dayOfWeek % 7 > 1  && currentTime.before(closingHour) && currentTime.after(openingHour)){
           System.out.println("Store is open");
        } else {
           System.out.println("Store is closed");
        }
```

Comment: Work fine :), but how i can do for that work in the two format hour thnks

Comment: what do you mean by two hour format? give me sample output

Comment: For example, my phone use format 00 to 12 where the 17:00pm will be 5:00pm in another phone, the format is 24, so 17:00 is the 17:00

Comment: It's not related to your device time format, whether it's 24 hour format or 12 format. when you get HOUR_OF_DAY from calendar, it returns you time in 24 format ;) if you want string formatting, don't hesitate to tell me to send you code snippet to format your out put :)

Comment: how i could change this 17, you konow here in colombia is 4:pm = 14:00 and show closed jejeje, because in code y put 17, and 04 is before that open

Comment: in Columbia 4:pm is 14:00? must not be 16:00? anyway, no need to change, calendar class handles everything  by itself, it's only a presentation and time object works in background, if you want set it in the code in 12 hour format use closingHour.set(Calendar.HOUR, 4) following with closingHour.set(Calendar.AM_PM, 1);

Comment: I am afraid that this will show the store as closed on Mondays. Using the obsolete `Calendar` class correctly isn’t that easy…

Comment: I've just edit it not be afraid, dayOfWeek % 7 > 1  this would omit cause of frightening. Saturday is 7 and Sunday is 1, so it works correctly